# struts2 revamp project --> compile error

Tags: java, struts2

I have below code but it has compile error. It is migrating from struts1 to struts2. I tried to search in the web but no use, e.g. "resetToken struts2" or "getLocalAddr request"...
Please help!!!

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

String serverNumber = request.getLocalAddr().substring(request.getLocalAddr().length()-1);
// *it said The method getLocalAddr() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest* ...

resetToken(request);
//*The method resetToken(HttpServletRequest) is undefined for the type CardAction*
```

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: Jdk version 1.6, Struts2-core version  2.1.8

Comment: Fix your web application version